# Put string in a text file into a Python variable

Tags: python

I have built some SAS code that dynamically produces URL strings and places them into a text file. I need a way to convert this string into a Python variable that I can then use in my Python code.

I've looked at some of the configparser based solutions and these seem a little elaborate for what I am trying to achieve.

Is there not a simple way to open a text file and convert it's contents into a variable string?

Thanks

Comment: How is your file formatted? Please provide a concise example of a few lines of your text file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        # access each line as a string here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myurls = open(myfile, 'r').readlines()
```

Will store the contents of `myfile` in `myurls` as a `list` with each line as a string element. I.e. each URL is a separate item that can be acessed independently.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your text is formatted, but something like this should work:

```
text_file = open('txt.txt', 'r')
lines = text_file.readlines()
```

lines should be a list.
You can test it like this:

```
print lines
for url in lines:
  print url
```

url should be a string.

Comment: What is the point of posting this answer when mine uses exactly the same concept already?

Comment: I was mid-post when you put yours.

Comment: OK but generally it says when new answers have been posted. You should check these and then see if your answer is worth posting. If you then feel it can be improved, you should suggest an edit or leave a comment. There is no point in having duplicates; it overcomplicates things.